# Getting "Flow analysis was incomplete, some code may be missing" on WinDbg

Tags: windows, x86-64, windows-10

I wanted to perform static analysis on the Win32 function `CreateFileW`, so I loaded `kernel32.dll` using WinDbg and perform the command `uf kernel32!CreateFileW`.

But I am seeing the following output instead.

```
0:000> uf kernel32!CreateFileW
Flow analysis was incomplete, some code may be missing
kernel32!CreateFileW:
00000001`80024b60 ff2582d50500    jmp     qword ptr [kernel32!_imp_CreateFileW 
(00000001`800820e8)]
0:000> uf kernel32!_imp_CreateFileW
No code found, aborting
```

Did I made any mistake?

Answer (score 1):

kernel32!CreateFileW is just a thunk in latest windows
which can be observed by the import call

```
jmp     qword ptr [kernel32!_imp_CreateFileW (00000001`800820e8)]
```

The Function is implemented in kernelbase!CreateFileW

You cannot disassemble a pointer like you do

```
uf kernel32!_imp_CreateFileW
```

x64 uses RIP relative Addressing

you have to add the size of instruction to the Symbols Address and add the Relative Address in the Instruction and dereference the pointer to get the correct value for performing uf

Address Of Symbol

```
0:000> x KERNEL32!CreateFileW
00007ffb`d7744b60 KERNEL32!CreateFileW (CreateFileW)
```

length of instruction = 6 (ff25eac50500)

```
0:000> u KERNEL32!CreateFileW l1
KERNEL32!CreateFileW:
00007ffb`d7744b60 ff25eac50500    jmp     qword ptr [KERNEL32!_imp_CreateFileW (00007ffb`d77a1150)]
```

Rip Relative Constant in instruction

```
0:000> ? dwo(KERNEL32!CreateFileW+2)
Evaluate expression: 378346 = 00000000`0005c5ea
```

addup and dereference the vale and perform uf on that offset

```
0:000> ln poi(dwo(KERNEL32!CreateFileW+2)+KERNEL32!CreateFileW+6)
(00007ffb`d6db9d30)   KERNELBASE!CreateFileW   |  (00007ffb`d6db9db0)   KERNELBASE!CreateFileInternal
Exact matches:
0:000>
```

windbg already resolves the pointer  either 00000001`800820e8 in your post or  00007ffb`d77a1150 in my answer

you can directly dereference it to perform uf on the resultant offset

```
0:000> ln poi(00007ffb`d77a1150)
(00007ffb`d6db9d30)   KERNELBASE!CreateFileW   |  (00007ffb`d6db9db0)   KERNELBASE!CreateFileInternal
Exact matches:
```